# Camel fromF file routing

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

```java
fromF("file:input...")
    .choice()
    .when(A)
      .toD("file:dir1")
    .otherwise()
      .toD("file:dir2")
    .end()
```

When a file process, the original file stays input dir and new file is created on dir1 or dir2.
I actually like to move the file from input to either dir1 or dir2. Is there an option? Above code is simple one but actually has many process between.
For now I am using option `fromF("file:input?delete=true")`, so that there is no duplicate. But I am worried that the original file gets deleted somehow maybe when exception happens.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

delete (consumer)

If true, the file will be deleted after it is processed successfully. You can use it with peace of mind. File archiving with the noop parameter can be even better.

Answer (score 0):

the file will be deleted juste after it is processed successfully (the whole route).

you should use the path parameter delete like this :

```
fromF("file:input...?delete=true").choice() .when(A) .toD("file:dir1") .otherwise() .toD("file:dir2") .end()
```

this is the description from apache camel doc :

**delete (consumer)** :If true, the file will be deleted after it is processed successfully.